# Redirecting the Trace.axd output

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-3.5

I have a custom control that is show only with a given set of config values.

I want to capture the trace.axd data and output it to this control.

**web.config**

```
writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" 
...
<listeners>
 name="WebPageTraceListener"
    type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
</listeners>
```

I want to be able to load the trace.axd file in a usercontrol. Then have that usercontrol be loaded whenever needed.

Comment: Do you mean the whole request details tables, exactly as Trace.axd output them? How would that be different from using `<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" />` in your `web.config` file?

Comment: For certain reasons, we cannot just added it to the page. Who can see the trace needs to be controlled. So I have set all output to the webPageTrace, but want to control the output.

Comment: ***https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx***

ASP.NET displays trace messages whenever tracing is enabled for a page. (`trace.axd TraceViewer`)
To route Trace messages to an ASP.NET Web page, you must add a `WebPageTraceListener` object.

To view the ASP.NET and System.Diagnostics trace messages in a context outside an ASP.NET page, use a `TextWriterTraceListener` object to write the trace messages to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a working solution, with two caveats:

First, it will always render the trace output too early, because it's too late to do that in a [Page.ProcessRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.processrequest%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) override (the `Response` object has already been cleaned up), so we're forced to do it during the `Render` phase, which means we'll miss some messages (most notably `EndRender`).

Implementing that behavior in a control exacerbates the problem, since we'd have to ensure our control is the last thing to render on the page in order to avoid missing more messages. For that reason, I chose to implement a custom page class instead of a custom control class. If you absolutely need a control class, it should be easy to convert (but leave me a word here if you need help).

Second, the profiler object that owns the data, `HttpRuntime.Profile`, is `internal` to the `System.Web` assembly, and of course the trace rendering routine is `private` to the `Page` class. So we have to abuse reflection, break encapsulation, and basically be *evil* in order to do what you want. If the ASP.NET trace implementation changes in the slightest, we're SOL.

That said, here's the traceable page class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace StackOverflow.Bounties.Web.UI
{
    public class TraceablePage : Page
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets whether to render trace output.
        /// </summary>
        public bool EnableTraceOutput
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Abuses reflection to force the profiler's page output flag
        /// to true during a call to the page's trace rendering routine.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(writer);
            if (!EnableTraceOutput) {
                return;
            }

            // Allow access to private and internal members.
            BindingFlags evilFlags
                = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static
                | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            // Profiler profiler = HttpRuntime.Profile;
            object profiler = typeof(HttpRuntime)
                .GetProperty("Profile", evilFlags).GetGetMethod(true)
                .Invoke(null, null);

            // profiler.PageOutput = true;
            profiler.GetType().GetProperty("PageOutput", evilFlags)
                .GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(profiler, new object[] { true });

            // this.ProcessRequestEndTrace();
            typeof(Page).GetMethod("ProcessRequestEndTrace", evilFlags)
                .Invoke(this, null);

            // profiler.PageOutput = false;
            profiler.GetType().GetProperty("PageOutput", evilFlags)
                .GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(profiler, new object[] { false });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's its test page, which uses an `AutoPostBack` check box to demonstrate its behavior across postbacks:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestTracePage.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="StackOverflow.Bounties.Web.UI.TestTracePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>TraceablePage Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <h2>TraceablePage Test</h2>
    <p>
        <asp:CheckBox id="enableTrace" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True" Text="Enable trace output"
            OnCheckedChanged="enableTrace_CheckedChanged" />
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace StackOverflow.Bounties.Web.UI
{
    public partial class TestTracePage : TraceablePage
    {
        protected void enableTrace_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnableTraceOutput = enableTrace.Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

The test page renders like this on first load:

[image: Trace disabled]

Checking the box posts back and renders the trace output:

[image: Trace enabled]

Clearing the check box again suppresses the trace output, as expected.